# Performance issue with DictionaryEntry looping

Tags: c#

Currently I have 231556 of words collection and do below loop to check every words for duplication.

I am using this function :-

```
public bool IsContainStringCIAI(string wordIn, HybridDictionary hd, out string wordOut)
    {
        int iValue = 1;
        foreach (DictionaryEntry de2 in hd)
        {
            iValue = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(wordIn.ToLower(), de2.Key.ToString().ToLower(), CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace);
            if (iValue == 0)
            {
                wordOut = de2.Key.ToString(); //Assign the existing word
                return true;
            }
        }
        wordOut = wordIn;
        return false;
    }
```

It take around 20 hours to finish looping, because each word will be added in to dictionary after comparing if it is not same. Anything can I do to improve this loop? Thanks before.

Comment: I don't know if I've missed something, but a dictionary can't contain duplicates so I don't see the point of looping through it.

Comment: @Tharwen - for a given value of "duplicate". I assume the dictionary is built on a different comparison from that shown in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Can you convert your HybridDictionary to a Dictionary<string, string> where all the keys are already converted into a format you can compare (lower case, unwanted characters stripped out, whatever)? Then your method pretty much becomes this:

```
return hd.TryGetValue(wordIn.ToLower(), out wordOut);
```

And Dictionary is pretty fast ;]

Comment: You could use a custom `IEqualityComparer` to do this - use the `CompareInfo.Compare` line for `Equals`, and a similar `CompareInfo.GetSortKey(obj, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace).GetHashCode()` for `GetHashCode`.

Comment: @Rawling - yup. That would make more sense.